# Mutable NSHTTPURLResponse or NSURLResponse

Tags: nsurlconnection, iphone, nsurlrequest, nsurlcache

I need to modify response headers in an NSURLResponse. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you trying to modify the headers you get from the server?!  Do you mean NSURLRequest?

Comment: wait... no.. i mean NSURLResponse

Answer (score 9):

I was just talking about this with a friend. My suggestion would be to write a subclass of NSURLResponse. Something along these lines:

```
@interface MyHTTPURLResponse : NSURLResponse { NSDictionary *myDict; } 
- (void)setAllHeaderFields:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;
@end

@implementation MyHTTPURLResponse
- (NSDictionary *)allHeaderFields { return myDict ?: [super allHeaderFields]; }
- (void)setAllHeaderFields:(NSDictionary *)dict  { if (myDict != dict) { [myDict release]; myDict = [dict retain]; } }
@end
```

If you're dealing with an object you didn't make, you can try using `object_setClass` to swizzle the class out. However I don't know if that will add the necessary instance variable. You could also use `objc_setAssociatedObject` and stuff this all in a category instead, if you can support a new enough SDK.

Answer (score 3):

You can read them into a NSDictionary using the `allHeaderFields` method.

```
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    NSDictionary *httpResponseHeaderFields = [httpResponse
allHeaderFields];
```

To be 100% safe you'd want to wrap it with

```
if ([response respondsToSelector:@selector(allHeaderFields)]) {... }
```

Comment: Doesn't that return an NSDictionary instead of an NSMutableDictionary?

Comment: Yeah, that's what is there in the code sample. Here's the class reference http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSHTTPURLResponse/allHeaderFields

Comment: I don't see how an immutable dictionary will help me modify the keys/values

Comment: Ah... sorry, my mistake - what exactly are you trying to do by modifying the response? You could create a new NSMutableDictionary and use setDictionary to put the values from the original response headers, but I still don't understand the final goal here.

Comment: Use NSMutableDictionary *httpResponseHeaderFields = [[httpResponse
allHeaderFields] mutableCopy];  But really we could all help you much more if you would tell us WHY you want to modify fields in a response... are you looking to "fool" some kind of library getting back an NSHTTPURLResponse?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I wanted to modify the header fileds of http url response. I needed it because wanted to provide cached url response to UIWebView and want to fool the web view that the response is not expired (i.e. I wanted to change "Cache-Control" property of the header but to keep the rest of the headers). My solution was to use NSKeyedArchiver to encode the original http response and to intercept the serialization with delegate. In

```
-(id) archiver:(NSKeyedArchiver*) archiver willEncodeObject:(id) object
```

I check if the object is NSDictionary and if so, I returned modified dictionary (i.e with updated "Cache-Control" header). Afterwards I just deserialized the serialized response using NSKeyedUnarchiver. Of course you may hook to the unarchiver and modify the headers in its delegate.

Note that in iOS 5 Apple has added

```
-(id)initWithURL:(NSURL*) url statusCode:(NSInteger) statusCode HTTPVersion:(NSString*) HTTPVersion headerFields:(NSDictionary*) headerFields
```

which is not in the documentation (documentation bug), but it is in the public API of NSHTTPURLResponse

Answer (score -3):

You can do that, and you'd need `NSHTTPURLResponse` not `NSURLResponse`, because, in Swift, `NSURLResponse` can be used with many protocols rather than just `http`, such as `ftp`, `data:`, or `https`. As a result, you can call it to get the meta data info, such as expected content type, mime type and text encoding, while `NSHTTURLResponse` is the one responsible of handling HTTP protocol responses. Thus, it is the one to manipulate the headers.

This is a small code that manipulates the header key `Server` from the response, and prints the value before and after the change.

```
let url = "https://www.google.com"
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

        if let response = response {

            let nsHTTPURLResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
            var headers = nsHTTPURLResponse.allHeaderFields
            print ("The value of the Server header before is: \(headers["Server"]!)")
            headers["Server"] = "whatever goes here"
            print ("The value of the Server header after is: \(headers["Server"]!)")

        }

        })
        task.resume()
```

Comment: Your code manipulate a copy of allHeaderFields. It doesn't edit header inside NSHTTPResponse