# Modify headers in NSHTTPURLResponse

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, nsurlprotocol, nshttpurlresponse

Is it possible to modify a header on a NSHTTPURLResponse without using the method

```
initWithURL:statusCode:HTTPVersion:headerFields:
```

to create a new customized NSHTTPURLResponse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The response object returns an NSDictionary called `allHeaderFields`. It'd be ideal if you could modify that dictionary directly, but it's not an NSMutableDictionary. Which means that you can only do one of two things:

- Create a mutable copy of the current `allHeaderFields` dictionary, and use that in a new NSHTTPURLResponse (I know you said you didn't want to create a new NSHTTPURLResponse, but it's the simplest solution, you grab the other values from the original response, make an NSMutableDictionary that's initialized with the values of the original `allHeaderFields`, edit the field(s) you need to for whatever you're spoofing, and plug that into the new response.)
- Otherwise, you could implement a custom subclass of NSHTTPURLResponse that can modify the allHeaderFields object. Great answer that details the basics of how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2194751/465893), however it seems a bit more roundabout. Would only use this if you need to override an awful lot of HTTP Header fields.